# Spring Expresson Language, склейка коллекций

Tags: spring, jsp

Сразу скажу, что использую SpEL на JSP, для выборки нужных данных для отображения.

Пусть имеем:

```
public class Foo {List<Bar> listBar;...}
```

Где-нибудь в контроллере:

```
List<Foo> listFoo = ...
model.addAttribute("listFoo", listFoo);
```

Как написать SpEL, чтобы получить `List<Bar>` со всей коллекции? Можно получить с одного элемента:

```
<spring:eval expresson = "foo.listBar"/>
```

Можно получить получить `List<List<Bar>>`:

```
<spring:eval expresson = "listFoo.![listBar]"/>
```

но это двумерный массив. А нужно именно склеить эти коллекции, получив одномерный, как если бы мы использовали метод `addAll(Collection c)` для новой коллекции.

Можно ли как-то это сделать?